# Unity3D: iTween ValueTo() not working

Tags: unity, c#

I have the following code to animate the Camera's FOV change:

```
public float fieldOfView;
public Camera theCamera;
public float animTime;

private float origFOV;

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    origFOV = theCamera.fieldOfView;

    Hashtable h = new Hashtable ();
    h.Add ("from", (float)origFOV);
    h.Add ("to", (float)fieldOfView);
    h.Add ("time", animTime);
    h.Add ("onupdate", "OnFOVUpdate");

    iTween.ValueTo(theCamera.gameObject, h);
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other) {
    Hashtable h = new Hashtable ();
    h.Add ("from", (float)fieldOfView);
    h.Add ("to", (float)origFOV);
    h.Add ("time", animTime);
    h.Add ("onupdate", "OnFOVUpdate");

    iTween.ValueTo(theCamera.gameObject, h);
}

void OnFOVUpdate(float val) {
    theCamera.fieldOfView = val;
}
```

but I always get the following error when the script compiles:

`iTween Error: ValueTo() requires an 'onupdate' callback function and a 'from' and 'to' property.  The supplied 'onupdate' callback must accept a single argument that is the same type as the supplied 'from' and 'to' properties!`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -2):

I think you, basically, have to do what is asking for.
Implement `onupdate` function with parameters of the same row which your are planning to change.

Please find similar issue and solution here
https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/itween-valueto.62448/

Comment: It seems the requirement for implementing `onupdate()` was fairly obvious. I think it is the actual implementation asker is having trouble with, in the first place.

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad. Perhaps, solution could be to use iTween.Hash instead of normal Hashtable.